# how to customize a UITableViewCell? to the core of it

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

just like in other normal programming languages...
we can for example override the OnPaint() of the control...
can we do the same in xcode/cocoa touch/objective-c puzzle?

With no disrespect for the people who like it of course, and see that it's a limitless framework.

Comment: no, but funny from your part :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITableViewCell is a UIView subclass so you can override any UIView methods - including `drawRect:` method to perform whatever custom drawing you want to do...

Comment: I'm marking this the answer to my question because it's like override onpaint. Thanks. But for more information to beginners like me vikingosegundo's answer would be more helpful.

Comment: If another answer is more helpful (and it actually is) there's nothing wrong in accepting it really

Comment: :) It's ok, it's a site where people are asking directions, to solve problems. The ones who want to know how to override a control layout as in C# for example, must read your answer. And the ones who are trying to create custom cells and beginners like me, should read the other answer

Answer (score 2):

there a few ways of customizing UITabelViewCells. Subclassing is just one.

[Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1)
Interessting Chapters:

- Programmatically Adding Subviews to a Cell’s Content View
- Loading Custom Table-View Cells From Nib Files
- Subclassing UITableViewCell

Comment: THanks alot for your answer, it was VERY helpful. and sorry for not marking your answer.